# Why this list text cannot inherit the color blue of p?

Tags: html, css

It seems inheritance works for color but when I try to inherit the color its anchestor p, the list cannot take the color..Why does inheritance not work in this case?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>CSS (1)</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      p#parag{color:#009;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p id="parag">
      <ul id="nav">
        <li>test</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<ul>` is a **block-level** element.

`<p>` cannot contain block-level elements - from [the HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1):

> The P element represents a paragraph.
>   It cannot contain block-level elements
>   (including P itself).

So the browser is attempting to fix this error and produces this HTML:

```
<p id="parag"></p>
<ul id="nav">
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
<p></p>
```

The solution is to simply change the `<p>` to a `<div>`.

Comment: Yes, and the color of the UL will need to be set separately; or else wrap both the P and the UL in some parent element (such as a DIV) and place the color on that.

Answer (score 1):

`<ul>` (block level) is not valid within a `<p>` tag - no block levels allowed within `<p>` tags!

http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/p/bltags_paragrap.htm